# Which of these subsequences converge, and why?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ = $\frac{n}{n+1}$$(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$

I've been asked which of the following converge, ($a_{2k}$), ($a_{2k+1}$), ($a_{4k+1}$), or ($a_{6k}$)

Now, for $a_{2k}$ gives $\frac{2k(2k+1)}{2}$ which is even, thus $a_{2k}$ = $\frac{2k}{2k+1}$

In fact, for all of these examples of subsequences $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is even, thus

$a_{2k+1}$ = $\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}$

$a_{4k+1}$ = $\frac{4k+1}{2k+2}$

and $a_{6k}$ = $\frac{6k}{6k+1}$

Now, how do I see which subsequence is convergent? Because it seems to me that they all converge to 1

Comment: Well, for $2k$ you get $k(2k+1)$ which is not necessary even

Comment: @Zahlenteufel doesn't it give 2k(2k+1) which is an even x an odd which is thus even?

Comment: You also divide by two in the exponent.

Comment: Yeah simple mistake! I had a brainfart and thought even/2 => even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim isn't all that true, in fact for example if $k=5$, then
$$\frac{k(k+1)}{2}= \frac{5 \cdot 6}{2}=15.$$

---

For $a_{2k}$, we know it is
$$a_{2k}=\frac{2k}{2k+1}(-1)^{k(2k+1)},$$
so if we pick the subsequence with even $k$, we get
$$a_{2k} = \frac{2k}{2k+1} \to 1;$$
instead, if we pick the subsequence with odd $k$, we get
$$a_{2k} \to -1,$$
in fact we have that $k(2k+1)$ is product of two odds (since $2k$ is even $\Rightarrow 2k+1$ is odd).
This shows that $a_{2k}$ does not converge.

---

For $a_{2k+1}$ we have that
$$a_{2k+1}=\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}(-1)^{(2k+1)(k+1)},$$
so, proceeding just as before, we observe that the subsequence of odd $k$ gives us
$$a_{2k+1} = \frac{2k+1}{2k+2} \to 1;$$
instead the subsequence of even $k$ gives us
$$a_{2k+1} \to -1$$
since  both $(2k+1)$ and $(k+1)$ are odd.
This proves that also $a_{2k+1}$ does not converge.

---

For $a_{4k+1}$, we have that
$$a_{4k+1}=\frac{4k+1}{4k+2}(-1)^{(4k+1)(2k+1)},$$
where both $(4k+1)$ and $(2k+1)$ are odd, so we always have
$$a_{4k+1}=\frac{4k+1}{4k+2}(-1) \to -1.$$
Proving that $a_{4k+1}$ converges.

---

Lastly, for $a_{6k}$, we have
$$a_{6k}= \frac{6k}{6k+1}(-1)^{3k(6k+1)},$$
where $(6k+1)$ is always odd, meanwhile $3k$ is even when $k$ is even, so once again we have that there is the subsequence of even $k$ that converges to $1$ and the subsequence of odd $k$ that converges to $-1$.
This shows that also this last subsequence doesn't converge.